# Origen de la frase "hacer caso omiso"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, locuciones

En mi familia se acostumbra usar la frase *hacer caso omiso* en referencia a algo que hay que ignorar.  Tengo en conocimiento que este es el significado correcto de la frase, pero no logro entender cómo llega a tomar ese significado, dado que según la RAE, *omiso* se define como:

> ***omiso, sa***
>   *Del lat. omissus.*
>   1. adj. Flojo y descuidado.

¿Cómo es que *hacer caso omiso* llega a tomar el significado de *algo por ignorar* partiendo de un significado *flojo y descuidado*?

Aquí adjunto un ejemplo del uso de la frase:

> Papá: ¿Es cierto que van a empezar a cobrar por usar Facebook?
>   Hijo: No, eso no es verídico, es un rumor viejo que lleva circulando por años pero nunca sucede.
>   Papá: Ya entiendo. Es mejor *hacer caso omiso*, entonces.

Comment: Aunque en el DLE no lo pone *omiso* es el participio irregular del verbo [omitir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=R2ohfhq), con eso la expresión tiene más sentido.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La expresión completa aparece en el DLE con el significado que indicas:

> [**hacer caso omiso**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7pG16he#8umQFfG)
>
> 1. loc. verb. Prescindir de algo o no tenerlo en cuenta.

Como bien indica blonfu, este uso procede del **participio pasado irregular** del verbo **omitir**, que significa:

> [**omitir**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=R2ohfhq)
>   Del lat. *omittĕre*.
>
> 1. tr. Abstenerse de hacer algo.
> 2. tr. Pasar en silencio algo. U. t. c. prnl.

Aunque la edición de 1992 del DLE todavía recogía esta forma irregular del participio a modo testimonial, **hace varias décadas que nadie la usa como tal participio**: nadie dice *«el nombre del testigo ha sido *omiso del informe»* ni *«las estadísticas de tropas desplazadas están *omisas por seguridad»*, siendo lo correcto usar "omitido", "omitidas" respectivamente.

A día de hoy, el único uso de "omiso" en el sentido de "omitir" es el de la locución "hacer caso omiso".
Esto se puede comprobar [consultando "omiso" en el CREA](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=0&texto=omiso&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000), donde se ve que este es el único uso desde al menos 1975 (salvando un uso como sustantivo en un texto jurídico de México que habla de delitos de omisión).

Por eso el DLE ya no recoge "omiso" por separado con el significado que tiene dentro de la expresión.

Answer (score 2):

Si le hacemos caso a algo o alguien, lo tratamos de forma seria.

Con la edición de la palabra *omiso*, efectivamente estamos diciendo que **no** vamos a tomarlo en serio, es decir, apenas hacerle caso.